# NP hard implementation optimisation using Monte Carlo method

Tags: optimization, monte-carlo

I need to implement an algorithm ( or find an implementation) and optimise it using Monte Carlo method. This must be an NP hard such as the Travelling Salesman problem or the Knapsack problem. How can a problem be optimised exactly? Also I need to have the optimum value and compare with that, is there any site that gives the optimum for such problems? (since I can't find anything)

Thanks

Comment: Exhaustive enumeration *always* works.  Just be sure to choose test problems where this approach will yield an answer in reasonable time!

Comment: I have to use monte carlo, how can I determine the closes value to the optimum?

Comment: In your question you state that you need to know the true optimum for certain problems.  Provided you choose problems that are small enough, you can always find that optimum through exhaustive enumeration.  Compare that to what your Monte-Carlo method finds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is NP hard, then there is currently no way to solve exactly your problem if it is large. However, you can always test your heuristic algorithm on a smaller problem to see how it performs.

To solve a small NP-hard problem exactly, just form it in a discrete optimisation problem, most likely an integer linear program and use some existing solver (eg GLPK). You should be able to solve TSP with ~100 cities exactly on any modern computer.

Comment: Thanks, can greedy algorithms or nearest neighbour be used or are they an alternative to Monte Carlo?

Comment: These are approximation algos, they are not exact. But they do give a proof of upper bound, so you can at least compare the results with your MC result.

Comment: what do you mean an upper bound? and are their any links online that gives the exact solution so that I can compare to? since I can't find